# How to add a normal map texture and a diffuse texture on a model in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

When I add a normal map texture in cycles I do this - [image]

How to combine the normal map texture with a diffuse|color texture?
I don't have much knowledge about the nodes in cycles and I have no idea which node will combine them? Do I have to use the Color-Mix node? If so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I forgot that the color input is free and I knew this all the time, so that I see it is a funny question. However, thanks for the answer.

Comment: One more thing.. It seems that you are using the same image for both normal sockets (diffuse and glossy). If this is the case, you only need one image texture and normal map node and connect the last to both normal sockets.