# How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, pbr

I created some texture maps in MindTex to use in Blender, but I can't figure out how to properly hook them up. The maps I have:

```
 - Diffuse
 - Normal
 - Height 
 - Specular 
 - Gloss 
 - Self Illumination
 - Reflection
 - Ambient Occlusion
```

MindTex (left) vs. Blender (right)
[image]

As you can clearly see it's a pretty big difference.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASpMW.png) is my material node setup in Blender.

*In the examples I don't actually use self illumination or reflection images, but including this in the answer would be helpful*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This post is mostly outdated now and focusing on pre Blender 2.8 workflows before the implementation Principled BSDF. For a more up to date answer with PBR based solutions in mind see [Jachym's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/19307) instead.

First thing to have in mind is that you have some conflicting data, and some redundant maps that can't all be used at the same time because their functionality overlaps.

Second thing to have in mind is that Blender Cycles is a physically accurate renderer, that means the results tend to converge to a physically realistic solution. Some of the maps you have there are made as approximations of a real solution and as such are "incompatible" with the way Cycles works or at the very least not needed and will "worsen" the result.

**Ambient Occlusion AO** map is for example a map that is generally useful for real time rendering contexts, but usually not desirable in offline or realistic renders.
It can still be used in cycles to but the results will be "less realistic" and will partially ignore scene lighting.

[image: Ambient Occlusion]

As my default "base setup" I would recommend using the **Diffuse D** map on a *Diffuse Shader* color socket, the **Specular S** map as a mixing factor to mix it with a *Glossy Shader* (amount of shine or specularity)  and the **Glossiness G** map as input for the *Glossy Shader* *Roughness* socket (how clear or rough each reflection is):

[image: Base Setup]

Then the **Height H** map and the **Normal N** map are mostly self excluding, either use one or the other as far as I know. I am not very proficient with Norml maps but would go with the height map which is more versatile and easier to use but do as you please.

Either use the normal map with a *Normal Map* + *Bump Map* node connected to all used shaders,

[image: Normal]

Or use the **Height H** map as bump, as material displacement or ideally directly in a *Displacement Modifier* for actual geometry deformation

Bump

[image: Bump]

Material based displacement
[image: Material Displacement]

True Displacement using the *Displace Modifier* with a *Subsurf* to give it extra geometry to apply the effect
[image: True Displacement]

Answer (score 14):

### **Workflow for Principled BSDF**

Use *Non-Color* color space for most textures.
Only  Color and AO maps use *sRGB* color space

**List of maps and where to connect them**

- Diffuse/Color → *Base Color*
- Ambient Occlusion → use with Eevee, not with Cycles
- Metalness → *Metallic*
- Roughness → *Roughness*
- Gloss → add *Invert node* and plug into *Roughness*
- Specular/Refl → don't use, specularity is handled differently
- Bump → run through *Bump node* (as Height) and into *Normal*
- Normal → Use with *Normal Map node* and plug into *Normal*
- Height → Use as a Bump map or a Displacement Map.
- Displacement → run through *Displacement node* (as Height) and plug into *Displacement* input.
  - Don't forget to enable displacement in *Material options > Displacement*

[image]

**Further Reading**

- [CGBookcase How to use PBR Textures in Blender](https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/how-to-use-pbr-textures-in-blender)
- [SE: How to plug specular map into Principled Shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/88792/)
- [SE: What does Height Map mean in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137823/)

Comment: Nice answer, but really unsure about editing in a link to your own answer in the top-voted answer. Might set a bad precedent. Votes are meant to promote useful answers and your answer is already in second place, so quite discoverable.

Comment: @RayMairlot Good to know, I'll remove the link then :). Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 4):

I am no guru (:P), but as far as i can see:

It is a lot easier now in Blender 2.79 with the "Principled BDSF shader" in cycles shader setup:
1) plug the diffuse "gravel_d.png" into the colour socket
2) plug the specular "gravel_s.png" into the specular slider
3) plug the gloss "gravel_g.png" into the roughness slider (with an "invert colour node" in between)

Also:
4) plug the heightmap "gravel_h.png" into the displacement modifier after subdividing the surface that is being textured.

(The AO map is not used as blender will ray trace in cycles, the normal map is not used as the height map works better in a still image in cycles if there is time available to render it.)

Results should look like this:
[image]

The left hand sphere is not height mapped, the plane and the one on the right uses a subdivision surface modifier and then a displcement modifier with the "gravel_h.png" as the texture. the strength can then be adjusted to taste. As I inderstand it you could use the normal map and AO map to fake a lot of this for a faster render - e.g. animation / game; and i even hesitated to use the specular map as I have already likely got some/all of the info in the gloss map)

Here is the node setup:
[image]

Comment: My mistake there plugging spec into the spec tint socket

Comment: You can always [edit] your post to add info, or make corrections. No need to append corrections in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to generate a node setup for your textures is to use Node Wrangler.

First Enable the toolset in menu *Edit* -> *Preferences*, *Add-ons* tab: search for `Node Wrangler` and tick the check-mark in the results. It should stay enabled in future projects.

1. Select the Principled BSDF node in your material.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Navigate to, and **select** all relevant files. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or the *"Principled Texture Setup"* blue button. Node Wrangler will try to figure out the purpose of each file from the filename, so you should make sure your filenames are named correctly - have one of the keywords below:

| keyword used by [texturehaven.com](https://texturehaven.com) | socket | alternative keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **diff** | -> Principled BSDF: **Base Color** | `diffuse diff albedo base col color` |
| **disp** | -> Displacement: Height -> Material Output: **Displacement** | `displacement displace disp dsp height heightmap` |
| **nor** or **bump** | -> Bump: Height -> Principled BSDF: **Normal** | `normal nor nrm nrml norm`, `bump bmp` |
| **rough** or **gloss** | -> Invert -> Principled BSDF: **Roughness** | `roughness rough rgh`, `gloss glossy glossiness` |
| **spec** | -> Principled BSDF: **Specular** | `specularity specular spec spc` |
| ? | -> Principled BSDF: **Subsurface Color** | `sss subsurface` |
| ? | -> Principled BSDF: **Metallic** | `metallic metalness metal mtl` |

? - I couldn't find such texture on texturehaven.com

AO (ambient occlusion) maps will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Today's final result will be this:

[image]

#### Diffuse/Ambient Occlusion

Plug both into a *Color > MixRGB* node set to *Multiply*. Send the *MixRGB's Color* output into the *Diffuse BSDF's Color* input. There is also a second way to use an *AO* map. "eppo" recommends good ways to use *AO* maps [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?323373-how-do-i-use-ambient-occlusion-maps-in-cycles), saying the following. Something tells me you knew all of this, because you already had those two maps set up that way.

> a) Use Color mix, multiply AO and diffuse texture.
>
> b)Use AO as a Factor to mix two shaders - one general surface material, another - dirty surface.

*Diffuse on top, AO on bottom:*

[image]

*Material preview:*

[image]

#### Height/Normal

In general, choose either the Height or the Normal map. Using both gets repetitive.

The Height map get's fed through a *Vector > Bump* node before finally ending up in the *Diffuse BSDF's Normal* input. Send the image's color output straight into the *Height* input, and connect the *Normal* output to input. The *Strength:* and *Distance:* values can be tweaked to your liking, but I found the ones in the screenshot below to be effective for this texture. BlenderGuru has a good talk about bump mapping [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/basics-realistic-texturing/).

**The normal map can be combined with the bump map, but perhaps not quite how you think.**

First, add a *Vector > Normal Map* node. Make sure it is set to *Tangent* and connect the two color in/outputs. Set the *Strength:* value to *0.6* to match the *Bump* node. I figured out how to use the *Normal Map* node [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13590/how-to-add-a-normal-map-texture-and-a-diffuse-texture-on-a-model-in-cycles).

Add a *Converter > Vector Math* node. Set it to *Normalize*. Plug the *Bump* output into the top vector input, and the *Normal Map* output into the bottom vector input. Plug the *Vector Math* node's output into the *Diffuse BSDF's Normal* input.

*Current nodes:*

[image]

*Material preview:*

[image]

#### Gloss

This map can be used as a fac in a *Mix Shader* between everything created so far and a *Glossy BSDF* with a *Roughness:* value of *0.1* (don't forget to plug the *Vector Math* output into the *Glossy BSDF's Normal* input). However, I found it effective to first run it through a *MixRGB* node set to *Multiply*. The fac should be *0.7* and the bottom color, black.

*MixRGB node:*

[image]

*Nodes currently:*

[image]

*Material preview:*

[image]

#### Specular

I'm going to guess the last map is a *Specularity* map and not a *Self-illumination* map because rocks don't generally glow. :)

Simply connect the color output to the *Roughness:* value of the *Glossy BSDF* node. You can read more things to do [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?232692-Cycles-Specular-Maps), but I thought that this was the best for this particular situation.

*Final nodes:*

[image]

*Material preview:*

[image]

Final .blend:

[image]

Comment: How come you didn't plug the vector into the diffuse & specular? I thought they would both use it?

Comment: @DavidPrentice They would. I took the wrong screenshot, but was pressed for time and couldn't fix it. Sorry. By the way, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @DavidPrentice I updated the screenshots; sorry again for the confusion. Also thought I'd mention that the .blend file doesn't have the connection that you mentioned that I missed. You will have to add that yourself.