# How to texture a model in blender?

Tags: texturing

I'm playing around with applying texture diffuse, normal maps and speculars to 3d models. So I have downloaded a premade one and tried to play around with it. However i can't seem to apply the textures properly to the model.

I found it here http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/katarina-70638.html

Everything is in the zip file, just need some help with applying the texture, normal & specular in blender. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer here and see if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles/55251#55251

Comment: See my answer to [How to properly hook up various maps types together in cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55254/20508).

Comment: I'm even more confused now lol. Do i not need to unwrwap it or something first? And theres only 3 things I have to add to it, main texture, specular and normals. I dont see any specular nodes. Care to explain?

Comment: You have to unwrap before applying textures, but my guess is the file you downloaded is typically already unwrapped to match the textures it comes with. See my answer, it explains how to use a specular map, see *glossiness*