# Principled BDSF, which map to use for roughness or gloss?

Tags: texturing

I am using CrazyBump maps to put into the Principled BDSF node. Which one would you use for the roughness? I did not get a gloss map is this not the software to use? If not what software do you use? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you having issues with crazybump or with blender? If you could clarify a bit more it would help us out.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88792/how-to-plug-specular-map-into-principled-shader/106275#106275

Comment: Well crazy bump gives me colour, occlusion, disp?, specular, and normal. Which one of those would I use to insert into the roughness slot of the Principled BDSF. I have watched videos that say to use a glossy map but which of the crazy bump maps is glossy, or where can I make a glossy map. Thank you.