# Turbosquid model Vray SSS shader to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, subsurface-scattering

I have a problem of bought [Turbosquid female character](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-woman-girl-female-model/895500) which was build with 3Ds max and Vray translating to Blender Cycles shaders.
The main problem is with diffuse and Subsurface scattering. Vray SSS shader has a two levels of SSS textures (deep and medium) and ammount texture (read mask) therefore there is a problem matching the result in Cycles.

I have tried to go around that with combining (with mix RGB node) diffuse texture and medium level SSS texture for diffuse and the shame with deep SSS texture. But the result in not quite there.

I have run out of time and ideas how to solve this situation.

Here is a comparison of a model rendered with Vray(3ds max) and my try of matching the look
[image]

and here is a shader setup used in render for comparison.
[image]

Hope for some helpful insight of experienced Blender users or a redirection on some useful content.

Comment: Hello, looks like both models are lit very diferently, maybe try with a more directional light ?

Comment: Yeah that's true. I'm using different HDRi. Maybe it's not the best representation of a comparison. Biggest problem I have is a red(ish) hue on large areas on the skin and the lips color among the other things. There is also similar problem with reflection(specular).

Comment: AFAIK, the Principled BSDF isn't really made to handle a specular map, but to take a single specular value and modulate the behavior of a couple of other settings based on that.  I wonder if you can map one of these SSS images to the subsurface radius? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106275/110840

Comment: Hi :). Check out this answer: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972). The reddish hue is probably caused by too high scattering value. I'd suggest values around 0,01, but hard to say without seeing the textures.