# How to use emissive and mask textures in blender cycles 2.79?

Tags: texturing

I got a lava texture from poliigon.con and noticed that there are 2 types of maps that I have never encountered. One is an "emissive" map, and one is a "mask" map. Will I need to use these maps along with the Diffuse, Gloss, Normal, and Displacement maps to improve the realism of the texture??If so, how do I properly plug these in in blender cycles
 2.79?

Textures:https://poliigon.com/texture/2778

Comment: You don't "*plug these in in blender 2.79*", you plug them for a render engine, and that will largely depend on the render engine you plan to use, which you never mention. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles/

Comment: How would I plug them in the Cycles render engine using the principaled bsdf shader? The post you referred to does not say anything about emission or mask maps.

Comment: No it does not. Please edit your question add all the relevant details and tag it properly with a Cycles tag, so people can give you an acceptable answer.