# How to use opacity map in Blender?

Tags: texturing

I have textured my object in Quixel and have an opacity map due to a portion of this object being glass. The issue is that when I try to use the opacity map my entire object has transparency and not just the glass. Could someone please show me a node set up (using principled shader) with an opacity map included?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The article suggested has the opacity plugged into the base color, so where do I plug in my diffuse map?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and update your question with  information. Add images that illustrate what you have so far and how it is not working for you.