# FBX import Sets up odd material set up - what goes where?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, .fbx

I have noticed that some of the FBX files I import into Blender 2.79b come with their own textures (yay!). But, I am not sure exactly how everything should be plugged into the node tree that comes in. And, how these maps get controlled by the node.

For example, this crane model comes with the following materials:
Mat0_c  -- I know this is the diffuse color
mat0_g  -- I am pretty sure this is the glossy map. Where does it go?
mat0_n  -- Normal map, easy peasy for plugging into the node
Mat0_r  -- Reflective? Where?
Mat1_c  -- color again..
Mat1_s  -- what the heck is this? Shiny? Would this be considered a "metalness" map? (Unfortunately, the Mat1_s map I have is corrupted so I can't even begin to figure out what it does. Since this model has been sitting on my desktop for about a year, I can't even remember where it came from!)

[image: fbx default node tree]

This is slightly similar to [How to properly hook up various maps types together in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles)

However, what I think I am really asking about is the FBX materials node that auto propagates when I import an fbx file. I cannot find any specific documentation about that "default" material.

For example, the material has one image texture that shows up as the default, but it is named diffuse texture.001. The actual image map is the mat0_c, but it doesn't call it that.

The Mix Color/Alpha: what map is it expecting and which socket is it supposed to be plugged into? Should the image map be set to non-color data? Is this for adding something like decals to the model?

The Mix Color/Diffuse: I plugged the image map into the bottom socket. What does the top color do and what are my options with changing that? The fac controls the mix of the two together, obviously. But, what can I do with it? If I use another image map or procedural texture, what, if anything, does that gain me?

And, the Mix Color/XXXX seems to be a renamed node. Is this simply a shader mix node?

I have watched tons of youtube tutorials on building materials and have a pretty strong, albeit basic, understanding of building texture nodes. However, I am coming from a photography background and not a gaming background. So, I struggle with the workflow.

Is there a tutorial on this specific node group that will help me to control it better and be able to customize it? Or, other documentation?

Comment: could you upload the Mat0_r, Mat0_c, Mat1_c and Mat1_s and I can try and figure out what each does and how to put the nodes together if you need? Quick question. What blender version are you doing this in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly hook up various maps types together in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles)

Comment: I have edited my question above to, hopefully, clarify what I have been scratching my head about.