# How to Make Metal Mesh using PBR texture....?

Tags: texturing

[image: Thats what i want to make]

[image: Pbr textures for Metal mesh]

I dowloaded this texture form CC0 textures. I am trying to appy it for long time using node editor but i dont know where i am lacking. Please help me out.

Comment: Is.. this question about Blender, somehow? If so, which version are we talking about? Which render engine? Showing a screenshot of your model would be a good start. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please). It has a lot of info about how to ask good questions. Other than that, there are many, many good tutorials on youtube about how to create a PBR material in Blender. If you want to add info to your question, please use the edit link below it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles/55251#55251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a Principled Shader, the simplest route is just plugging the images into the same-named slots.  The only tricky parts are:

- any grayscale maps should use the "Non-Color Data" setting so that Blender doesn't             adjust the gamma
- you need to mix in a Transparent shader to get the transparent parts in this case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot its really help me. I am using Blender 2.8, only difference is in Node editor in setting Using key "N". We have to choose "Alpha hashed" instead of "Alpha blend" it gives best result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the node which i used in blender 2.8 and Out put result[image: Output result]
[image: Node for Metal Mesh using PBR texture]

But in EEVEE engine for perfect result we have to choose blend mode as "Alpha Hashed" in the setting of Node editor using "N" key. if we use Alpha Blend then their will be some problem in mesh as we clearly see in image. [image: Alpha Blend] [image: Alpha Hashed]