# Im new and confused what these files mean... (new to blender)

Tags: texturing

So I've been trying to extract models from the game "Rust". In the game, there is a crossbow and when I looked through the game files I've noticed these four images. I can use the albedo one for texture painting and it gets the corrects textures. But I was wondering what these other images are? Should I use them for anything? Thank you https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTzra.jpg

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

The first image is indeed the albedo, which is the base for a material. The rest are for things like bumps, roughness etc. The second one is for roughness, the third one is the normal map, and the last one is the displacement map.

Comment: Okay, thank you i wasnt sure which ones were which but I have another question. Would it be possible to apply these in blender? To give the model roughness and such? Or is it just for the game? I see that one image has the same color that you get when you go into the sculpting mode. Thanks again.

Comment: It is, you can apply these to any model by going to the shading tab (top bar) and adding an image to each type you need. Here's a tutorial showing how it's done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIq7BG4BVvo

Comment: Okay, ill try this tutorial out. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!