# How do I use texture maps in Cycles nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, image

What I did:

- Change render engine to Cycles
- Add Suzanne
- Add plane
- Scale plane by 5
- Change environment texture to HDRI from https://hdrihaven.com/
- Change Suzanna node setup
- Change plane node setup (use default principled BSDF, add image textures for diff (diffuse), spec (specular), rough (roughness), normal, disp (displacement))
- Change all image textures to non-color data except for diff (diffuse) and normal

The specific texture for the plane is https://texturehaven.com/tex/?c=wood&t=rough_wood. I am given the option to download:

- Diffuse
- AO (unused)
- Bump (unused)
- Displacement
- Normal
- Roughness
- Specular

**Is this the correct node setup to use the texture and how do I connect the unused textures?**

I am using Blender 2.82a. The wood plane looks flat to me even though I added the normal and displacement nodes.

Nodes:

[image: nodes]

Render:

[image: render]

Comment: then we should vote up the up to date answere using Principled BSDF

Comment: @JachymMichal If you think the answer on the linked question needs updating then I think it would have been better to update it or add a new answer. There are plenty of duplicates that point to it.

Comment: @RayMairlot I've posted a new answer there covering most textures :). Thanks for the suggestion. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/

Comment: Since the question is closed, my answer doesn't make sense for the one it "duplicates", and it's short, I'll write it here: you can enable node wrangler in addons (edit -> preferences -> search for "node wrangler"), select the Principled BSDF node, press CTRL+SHIFT+T, navigate to, and select all relevant files, confirm the selection by pressing ENTER or clicking the blue button. The node setup should be created automatically. EDIT: after 2nd thoughts, I'll write an answer there, advising to rename the files so they can be recognized by Node Wrangler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things you missed :).

Maps to use:

- Diffuse. Plug into *Base Color* input.
- Roughness. Plug into *Roughness* input.
- Normal. Use with *Normal Map node* and plug into *Normal input*. Select UV map to use.
- Displacement. Use with *Displacement node* and plug into *Displacement* input.

  - You need to enable material displacement through *Options > Displacement > Displacement and Bump* (works only in Cycles)
  - Only works if your geometry is subdivided.

---

- Bump. Don't use here, since you have a *Normal map* (which works better)
- Specular. Don't use here. (It's more complicated, but I won't address that here)
- Ambient Occlusion (AO). Don't use with Cycles, use with Eevee.

[image]

Comment: For anyone skimming through, the plane needs to be subdivided for the displacement to work.

Comment: I think this answer should be under the original question of which this here and many others are a duplicate. So all links that point to this question still point to the most up to date answer.