# What is this map, and how would I use it?

Tags: node-editor

This is another Splatoon Blender question that I have. It's regarding this texture that came along in a model. It's called "m_star_mfk"

[image]

My Splatoon Blender teacher told me that it's a "normal map that is supposed to disturb the shading normals of the object to lead them in random directions." I'm having some trouble understanding this, and even applying it. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Like Bump map, Normal map is made to fake 3D, with no additional faces on your object, so it keeps your object light. GhostOwl explains how to use it in the Shader Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a regular normal map to me, which is used to add texture to a surface without changing the actual geometry. A normal map contains surface angle information, and a bump map contains surface height information.

Here is a good article on normal maps: https://cgcookie.com/articles/normal-vs-displacement-mapping-why-games-use-normals

And here is a screenshot of a simple node setup for a normal map and what it looks like rendered on a simple plane with a point light in Eevee. I hope this helps!

[image: Normal Map on plane]

Comment: So, sRGB, right?

Comment: @Velepexon Normal maps should be set to *Non-Color*. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972) is a useful overview.