# which PBR Metal or Specular workflow does Blender use?

Tags: materials

Seeking advice with anyone experienced with these apps and which workflow to choose.
which PBR Metal or Specular workflow does Blender use?
pipeline will be Quixel + blender + Unity PBR Metal or Specular workflow

Comment: In my experience, Blender handles both equally well.

Comment: This being said, I believe it's easier to convert from metallic/roughness to specular/glossy than it is to go the other way around, so it may keep more doors open to choose metal-rough.

Comment: Hello :). I believe Principled BSDF works better using [metalness workflow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/) since specularity is handled a bit differently.