# How to use normal bent texture in cycle(anisotropic reflections)

Tags: normal-map

In ff7re game character texture,there is one NB texture,some people consider it as normal bent.[image: NB map]

So how to use the map in cycle ?(It's a map for hair)

Comment: it looks like a normal map, you need to create an Texture > Image Texture node and load the image, and plug it into the Color socket of a Vector > Normal map node. Then plug this last node into the Normal socket of the Principled BSDF (or Diffuse)

Comment: Hello :). [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972) covers how to use a Normal map texture.

Comment: @moonboots   the map is not exactly normal map,the hair mesh already has a normal tangent map,someone told me it's a flowmap or tangent shift map for anisotropic reflections.

Comment: oh ok, my bad then