# Questions about applying maps on ripped models

Tags: texturing, normal-map

Even though I'm not new at 3d art, I'm a beginner at blender, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I recently got around ripping models from a game called Identity V, but the problem is: I don't know how to apply the normal maps and other maps I don't even know what they are.

This is how the model looks in game (detail to how the fabric seems kinda velvety, from the way it changes colors as he moves)

[image: This is how the model looks in game]

And this is how the model looks in Blender on the Material Preview, only with its textures.

[image: This is how the model looks in Blender]

Finally, here are all the textures and maps I could recognize as his. I still have the other images NinjaRipper extracted, if needed.

[image: All the textures and maps]

I know this is a really beginner question but I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me.

EDIT (? How do I even do this): [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232) question helped me with applying the Normal and Roughness map (on the picture, body alpha smth.png) but didn't with the other maps, since there are no answers about how each map looks like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly hook up various maps types together in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles)

Comment: @susu it did help for the normal map, thank you! but I still don't know what to do with the other ones. the 'body alpha smth.png' seems to be a roughness map to make the dark blue part of the outfit that shiny velvet look, but it's obviously missing something (probably the other two maps). I tried downloading the blend file on the question you sent  to compare the maps with mine and try to find out what they're for, but it was taken down...