# Can anyone give me a detailed description on all the maps in blender?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Can anyone give me a detailed description on how to use different types of maps(eg: albedo,opacity, normal, displacement,et cetera et cetera ); which all maps are to be set to non-color data or sRGB; if I should use a certain shader node to connect some maps(like how we use a normal map node to connect a normal map to the principled BSDF; *and yes, I do know we have to use a normal map node for that*). If you guys know a video or a website which explains it **all**(*emphasis on* **all**), then I'm all ears. Thank you UwU

Comment: Hello :). You're in luck, here's an answer covering many of them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972

Comment: If you find some that are missing from the list, I'll be happy to edit them in :).

Comment: ayyy thank you! btw can you explain what is an opacity map? i did not find it on the list .btw thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello :). Opacity map controls transparency. Plug it into the Alpha input. More here: https://www.katsbits.com/codex/opacity/

Comment: thank you again! you have been a great help.^^

Comment: No problem, good luck on your Blender journey :).