# How to apply texture in blender 2.9

Tags: texturing

I created an object but i would like to put a wood texture on it, how apply with blender 2.9?

Comment: Hello :). What kind of texture? A [procedural like this](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/10/20/procedural-cc-0-pbr-wood-shader/)? Or an [image-based like this](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/wood-flooring-044)?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange, please enhance your question to be more descriptive, embed images to showcase the outcome you're expecting

Comment: Hi :) I mean an image-based like this : https://www.poliigon.com/texture/wood-flooring-044

Comment: Related: [How to hook up various maps types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)