# Applying materials to FBX file from 3dsky

Tags: modeling, texturing, import

I'm very new to blender and have very little experience with anything in the node editor.

I'm doing a blender guru tutorial linked below. He states you can download models and simply annd plug the materials into where they should be.

Blender guru tutorial: https://youtu.be/wrzSrjAY69c

So I'm trying to then replicate it with this model https://3dsky.org/3dmodels/show/lawson_velvet_gray_2_seater_couch and just getting stuff with the different textures and bump maps etc. Could someone show me a screen show on how they would set up the node for the back wooden bits?

Thanks

Comment: Hello :). You need to show what you've got so far, or you probably won't get much help :).

Comment: Related: [How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)

Comment: Thats the problem, I'm not really getting anywhere. In imgur link below shows where I'm at but obviously there are many issues like wood not facing thr right direction, not knowing what bump maps mean what or anything really.

https://imgur.com/a/gROKkKm

Comment: Hey :). That is actually an intermediate tutorial where he skips a lot of things. I'd suggest to try Blender Guru's Donut tutorial where he explains and teaches all the stuff you need to now first :).

Comment: Yeah I started it but to be totally honest kind of got bored on that one, I'll get back to that one then! Also might do his chair one as I'd expect some of the issues I'm facing will be in that one too!  Thanks though, really appreciated!