# Normal map makes the texture too dark at an angle?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, objects, normal-map

Normal map makes the texture too dark at an angle. If the light source is placed south or left of the plane, the textures is visible. Otherwise, the entire wall looks dark. Does anyone know the solution to this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You forgot to tun your normal map through a Normal Map node.

Comment: Related: [How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)

Comment: thank you very much