# Downloaded PBR texture looks different in Blender

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm looking for a way to further improve the look of my metal texture.
I'm trying to use [this texture from a free pbr website](https://3dtextures.me/2021/03/18/metal-scratched-008/). (first image)

[image]

If I just import and use the provided textures it looks more like a glass texture than a metal.
I tried to toyed with the roughness, but it tends to "sacrifice" the  reflectiveness of the metal.

[image] [image]

Any idea how should I improve it.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The main difference is in the lighting. They're using 3-point lighting, while you're using an HDRI. Also, make sure the required textures are set to *Non-Color*, it makes a big difference.

Comment: Related: [How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have node wrangler turned on, you can just select the BSDF node and then hit [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [T], then select all the material files in the download and the materials will be attached properly.

Then, make sure you're working in Cycles render engine to make it look more like the material preview.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. But I actually did according what you have said. In fact, if i directly import the material and plug it in to it corresponding node in principle bsdf it will look like the "glassy metal" I share above. I have to use node wrangler to preview the provide roughness map and toy with it(roughness) to remove the glassy feel and end up with image 2. Usually I don't mind with the result of image 2 if it was for background mode, but if it for a "main item" I would to further improve it

Comment: Did you do as Jaychm Michael said, and make sure you're using the non-color info?

Comment: I figure out the problem, after changing it to non color (even roughness and metallic)  I got the result. I was in rendered view and after switching from  material preview it woks. 

However, with such low poly I kinda expected it to update it as well..