# How to make colored Ambient occlusion?

Tags: texture-baking

When I bake AO, white color comes out all the time. How can I get an ambient occlusion bake on the color of the object or the texture of the object itself?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Ambient Occlusion is supposed to be B&W, then added on top of Base Color. [See this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)

Answer (score 3):

Ambient occlusion maps are supposed to be grayscaled. If you want a colored map, change the bake type to combined or color (I use Blender 3.0 so the GUI is different than 2.79, sorry!):
[image]