# How do I use these image textures to make my material?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Here are some images of what the model I downloaded is supposed to look like

[image]

[image]

[image]

All I know at the moment is to click "principled bsdf" and press ctrl+shift+t and choose the images that the material is supposed to have. But this does not work properly.

I also know how to select the faces of an object and in UV edit mode place the faces on the image and hit assign on the material properties tab to place the material on the selection.

My question is- how do I connect all the images that texture this model correctly? Here are what they are called:
Floor_mat_diffuse

Floor_mat_glossiness

Floor_mat_ior

Floor_mat_Normal

Floor_mat_Reflection

Wall_mat_Diffuse

Wall_mat_Diffuse_01

Wall_mat_Glossiness

Wall_mat_Glossiness_01

Wall_mat_ior

Wall_mat_ior_01

Wall_mat_Normal

Wall_mat_Normal_01

Wall_mat_Reflection

Wall_mat_Reflection_01

An image titled '30' which looks like it's the base pattern on top of which all these effects are stacked.

The files also come with two .CUBE files- are these used in blender?

This file is something I purchased on turbosquid so I don't think I can upload it. I already contacted the creator but no answer yet- the download came with a 3ds max file, but I'm using blender- hopefully someone can help me use these materials! Are all of these images supported on blender?

It sounds like I need to make two materials with a bunch of different shaders in there and mix them all together, is this correct? I would appreciate someone showing me what the setup would look like, and what nodes to connect the images to. Let me know if you would like to see more images. This is what the model looks like.

[image]

Comment: Well, it looks like there's one material for the floor, and 2 materials for the wall (the second (_01) either being a variant or a copy). Aside from the names that match up perfectly with the accompanying spots on the Principled BSDF, Diffuse connects to BaseColor. Reflection can either mean Roughness or Specular, and Glossy can mean either Metallic or Roughness - you will have to see for yourself which makes more sense. However, sometimes both are not needed as one is meant for a metal/rough workflow and the other is meant for specular/gloss (your choice for what you need).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thanks for the help! I appreciate you taking the time to explain this- I also found this link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-in-cycles/174461#174461 when my question was closed- I don't know if people can see closed questions? But if someone ends up here, that should help.