# New to Blender Materials, Proper use of these texture files using Nodes?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

Hello there I have a series of textures I'm trying to figure out how to use in Blender shader nodes.
I'm not new to blender but I am new to use and setting up Shader nodes especially separating colors for different uses.

The First texture is the team colors, it uses RGB channels in order to put the team colors on the model. red is the main color green is the stripe i don't know what the blue is? dirt maybe?

The one I am most stuck on is the second texture, I know that the red Channel is the emissive but I'm not sure what Blue and green is. and I'm really not sure how to use the texture with nodes.

The third texture the gray one I think is the normal map?

The fourth is the color diffuse

and I'm not sure what the last bright white texture is? I think it's ambient occlusion, I'm not sure how to use that one in nodes either.

If someone could show me a proper node set up for this it would seriously help me out, I have so many other units to put together using this exact same node structure.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the name of the images, usually it describes what the channels contain. AO for ambient occlusion, albedo for color, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I saw some of that, I still don't know how to properly utilize the textures in Blender nodes.

Comment: If the files have the correct naming convention you can use Blender's built-in Node Wrangler to automatically add the correct files to the correct node inputs. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP3_WOl4aco) is a quick tutorial on setting up and using Node Wrangler to add your images.

Comment: That did help a little bit, but unfortunately, these are not standard textures. I still don't know how to separate them into the maps i need.

Comment: Can't help with that one I'm afraid. Where did the textures come from?

Comment: At first glance the first two ones contain different data in each of the R, G and B channels. 3rd one looks like a bump map, 4th an albedo and 5th an AO map

Comment: The Textures came from Deserts of Kharak, I'm trying to piece them together in blender. 
I tried using node wrangler, but it doesn't know how to assemble them because they are not standard, funny enough it doesn't even connect the AO map, the one I thought it would get. 
and yeah I know the first two textures contain data in their RGB channels, I just don't know how to separate them in blender into the parts I need then hook those into the Nodes.

Comment: Never heard of "Deserts of Kharak" but if it's a game, game engines usually use their own proprietary file formats which can be a nightmare to decode.

Comment: It's not a proprietary format, it's just using color channels. I know it can be taken apart by blender, I've seen people do it, I just don't personally know how to do it with nodes, that is my question.

Comment: Look, we can't really do much here that you can't do yourself : Set every image texture but the 4th one to "Non-color", and try to plug the output in every input of a Principled BSDF shader and you'll see what should go into what when your shader updates. Use a separate RGB node for the first 2 textures

Comment: I'm hoping someone sees this that can. I know one person on here knows how, he helped me out with an SGA texture before, he was very helpful, Martin I think his name was.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-in-cycles) (OK I see it doesn't, still leaving the link)

Comment: Actually this does help a little thank you, I can use this to at least piece together parts of it.

Comment: If there is a modding community for that game, chances are some people already figured out how the channel packing is done and you could at leask ask the question directly to these communities. Here all we can say it to use Split RGB nodes and set the right color transform.