# Model has SRGB textures and no main texture. How do I combine?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

This model has liner SRGB textures and I'm really new to shader nodes and stuff and I'm really confused on how I'm supposed to get the texture to be the right colors with the output.

These are the images

[image: Skin Color 1][image: Skin Color 2]

And then I found that this is the base color somewhere:

```
{
      "ParameterInfo": {
        "Name": "BaseColor_0",
        "Association": "GlobalParameter",
        "Index": -1
      },
      "ParameterValue": {
        "R": 1.0,
        "G": 0.577581,
        "B": 0.38643,
        "A": 1.0,
        "Hex": "FFFFC8A7"
      },
```

Comment: Maybe of some help: [How to properly hook up various maps types in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209708/60486)