# Export materials / texture from unreal 5.2 to Blender 3.6

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I've exported some characters from Twinmotion, then into Unreal. I now need to export them into Blender.

I need help understanding how to apply the textures in Blender. They export in PNG format, and I've added the Basecolour and Normal which seems OK. My question is how to apply the other files.
Thanks for any help suggestions

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/19307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the overall setup in Blender would look like this :

<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Open image in new tab to see it enlarged
[image]

I will go through each element using the names in your first screenshots for clarity

#### ColorMap

[image]

As you understood already, this one it plugged in the Base Color socket. This is the only node whose color management is "sRGB". All the other nodes must use "Non-Color".

#### MaskMap

[image]

Considering the name, and it being followed by different "tint"  colors, I assume this one is three color masks in each RGB channel, meant to tint the base color at your wish.
In my setup, I featured only using the G channel's mask. Use the Separate RGB node to pick any mask you want, add a Mix Color map, put the base color in socket A, the mask in socket Factor, and the tint color you want in socket B. I set it up only for the G mask, but you can add the other masks with two other Mix nodes as well ; all you have to do is add two more mix nodes, plug the mask in the factor and plug the previous mix node's output to A.

#### TangentMap

[image]

Uses the "F" map. It looks like it covers a different part of the mesh (either via a different material assignation or more likely a different UV map?) and is plugged as TangentMap in the hair material settings, and it has nothing in its B channel, so perhaps its R and G channels are used for hair's anisotropy.

Hence, I used a UV Map node to select a different UV made for the hair that you probably already have, used a Separate Color to plug the two R and G channels in the anisotropic weight and rotation.

#### MetalRoughnessOccMap

[image]

As its name indicates, it's three maps in one, each in a different RGB channel: Metallic, Roughness, and Occlusion (aka Ambient Occlusion or AO).
Use a Separate Color to isolate the channels, and plug R and G in Metallic and Roughness, respectively. AO needs to be Multiplied to the BaseColor data stream using a Mix Color node.

#### Normal

[image]

As you guessed, it's the normal map. Plug it in a Normal Map node and then in the Principled BSDF's Normal.

Comment: thanks for taking the time, I'll work through it and post the end results.

Comment: Hi L0Lock, I added a mix color map like you said for the other masks so i now have RGB separated and mixed with the Basecolor connected to A on the MIX node. Im just struggling on where to put the result from each mix into the Multiply Node as it only excepts one connection. (you can probably tell Im new to this) I could send you a screenshot if thats easier- I cant work out how to do that either :-(  thanks again for your help

Comment: If you want to add all the tint masks, all you have to do is add two more mix nodes, plug the mask in the factor and plug the previous mix node's output to A.

Comment: This worked - thanks again :-)