# Blender cycles adding normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, normal-map

I baked a *Normal Map* and a *Diffuse Map*.

[image]

I tried to duplicate the object in new file and new scene by adding these maps to a plane, but I did not see the desired effect.

[image]

How can I use nodes to correctly add a *Normal Map* to an object?

Comment: A few things. Firstly a normal map is color data. Secondly why not use the UV map for both textures? See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13591/26720.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that normal maps are non color data. When choosing color data, some changes or conversions are applied, but you want the original rgb values of the normal map as information.

Comment: @Aoradon if the mesh is unwrapped that UV map will be used in any way (aka by default) so there isn't required any input for Image Texture node.

Comment: @MrZak Well TIL. Guess I've always assumed that normal is color data and that UVs don't auto apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the strength of the normal map node to 0 accidently.

Comment: Thanks. I have question. I will bake normal map - that i know but i need second bake diffuse map or combined?