# What is wrong with this simple node setup using textures from Poliigon?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I downloaded and tried this free material from Poliigon but I am unable to create it correctly.

This is the desired reflection/ result:
[image: Preview from the website]

This is my node setup:
[image: Nodes]

This is the current result:
[image: Result]

Which nodes here are wrong? I know maybe its about the invert node but removing that gave me minimal reflection, like a diffuse material. (The Gloss map is very whitish, So I thought I'll have to invert that. I've done it before many times using different texture sources)
And also, How do you use the reflection node?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the normal map as if it was a displacement map. You have to put it through a normal map node first and then into the normal input of your diffuse shader. And inverting the gloss is actually right.

Refer to this: [How to add a normal map texture and a diffuse texture on a model in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13590/how-to-add-a-normal-map-texture-and-a-diffuse-texture-on-a-model-in-cycles).

Comment: This is probably true, but I'm also going to point out that the lighting of the posted scene is not conducive to looking like the example either.